# Make the fixed content height matter

Tags: css

I have a situation kind of like this =>

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQpLqY

since my `#sub-header-content` has no fixed height and can grow when user interact, I would like to be able to not set the `height` of `#sub-header-content` manually, but make it automatically fit the child size.

```
#sub-header-content{
  background-color:purple;
  height:40px; //  WANT TO REMOVE THIS
}

#sub-header-menu{
  position:fixed;
  height:40px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand perfectly what you wanted, but I think setting min-height: 40px would do the trick.

Comment: Basically, right now I have to put the height/min-height manually. But if the height of the header is greater than the value I set (because of user interaction) I have to fix by code the height again or it will hide behind the content. What I would like, is that the #sub-header-content adapt to my #sub-header-menu height without me interacting with it